# Linq2Object : The Name "myTypeVariable" doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, nested, linq-to-objects

before ask this question, i tried to implement [this accepted answer on StackOverflow where given by user414076](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8592883/967770) but unfortunately i couldn't..

so i want to ask where am i wrong.. how should i go on for the efficient "Goal"..

in my winforms .Net4 project

i have two classes : Employee and Mods.. and a subclass of Employee : RM

**The Mods class carries data something like Government's "working permittance" rules**
i.e. if the employee is a Mechanical engineer then 
should work in one of the Mechanical Labs, 
should have salary min. "x" dollars per hour, 
-if has a successfull finished research- should take %1 of the research gain as a success prize,
etc. ..

**The employee class with many properties, and carries all of the data for an employee**
i.e. 
**name,** 
homeaddress, 
**List of phones,** 
List of Yearly Vacations, 
**List of Hospital Illness Papers,** 
List of Should_Attend_Seminars, 
**List of AcceptedWorkingRules,**
etc. ..

**The RM subclass carries details of the employee as it's working rules** 
i.e. 
**WorkingType** - is the salary hourly or weekly or monthly,Have extra commission or not etc. - , 
WorkingHours, 
**PermittanceID** -As a reference to the Mods Class ID Value- ,
etc. ..

My Goal is to select Employees from the static list of All Employees as seperate lists (if seperate list is not possible then grouped in a list)  of  which employees' RM.PermittanceID  are the same

i.e. 
RmPermittanceIdList_1 contains the employees which are have working type in (3,6,9,12) and permittance ID is 1

RmPerMittanceIdList_2 contains th employees which are have working Type in ( 3,6,9,129 an permittance ID is 2 
....goes on

{ i need these lists for a later use }

and what i tried and took error { The Name "em" doesn't exist in the current context } :

```
List<Employees> emps = from md in Program.modList 
                                   from em in Program.empList
                                   from emo in em.RmList
                                   where emo.EndDate > DateTime.Today
                                       && (emo.Worktype == 3 || emo.WorkType == 6
                                       || emo.WorkType == 9 || emo.WorkType == 12)
                                   group  o by emo.PermittanceID == md.ModId 
                                   into rm
                                   select new { id = em.ID, r = rm.ToList() };
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: `em` isn't accessible in the select-clause, because it's hidden by the grouping operation. But you are also grouping `o`, which isn't defined anywhere, and the group condition looks weird. It looks more like a join condition. Since it's a boolean expression you would never get more than two groups.

Comment: If `RM` is a subclass of Employee there should be no need to have both employee and RM instances - since the RM instance also carries the employee data. Do you really mean that the Employee contains an RM instance (i.e. more like a child object rather than a subclass)?

Comment: @OskarBerggren Thanks for quick answer.. Actually RM class is Employee.RM and implemented as List<Employee.Rm> in Employee class..So employee class carries the list of RM class instances, Not Rm carries Employee instances.. if i did, then sorry for the Term-Faults.. And im not expert may be i did wrong when i tried to grouping.. I guess i need to search whole List<Employee> and seperate them manually by Permittance ID.. but then i need to find a way to give name to new List for future usage ( permittance ids are right now 71 and in future they will grow ) can you give any idea for this please?